# Gitlab runner not picking jobs

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to set up a GitLab runner for a repository. I've installed and registered a runner on a remote machine. The runner in the Gitlab setting page is in the green light. Run untagged jobs has been set to true.
The pipeline is **running**, but all the jobs inside this pipeline are all **pending**. 
The status of the GitLab runner on the remote machine:
[image: Remote machine]
And here is my simple script of .gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test

image: "ruby:2.6.5"

build-ruby-bundler:
  stage: build
  script:
    - apt-get update -qq
    - ruby -v
    - which ruby
    - gem install bundler --no-document
    - bundle install --jobs $(nproc)  "${FLAGS[@]}"

rubocop:
  stage: test
  script:
    - bundle exec rubocop
```

Answer (score 1):

I just realized, I registered the GitLab runner in user mode, which I need to register in system mode using `sudo gitlab-runner register`.